# Correct syntax to pre-fill fields on Stripe Connect's oauth/authorize signup

Tags: stripe-payments

I am having difficulty getting fields to pre-fill on Stripe Connect's user authorization signup page based on the optional query string params listed on https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference.  This page identifies optional fields such as `stripe_user[product_description]`.

The default signup process works properly for me so the required params such as `client_id` and `response_type` are being set properly based on the url params.

But when I add an optional param like stripe_user[production_description] to the end, such as in the following, it is getting ignored:

`https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize&scope=read_only&stripe_landing=register&response_type=code&client_id=ca_MyClientId&stripe_user[product_description]=My%20Product%20description.`

If, however, while on a test user's new account signup page I simply add the query string to the end of the url params, e.g. by just appending `&stripe_user[product_description]=My%20Product%20description.` to the browser address bar, the product description field is hidden by Stripe, which I take to mean it is being received and recognized properly.

I have a feeling my syntax is off slightly somewhere so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just have it, for instance, in a href like so :

```
<a href="https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize&scope=read_only&stripe_landing=register&response_type=code&client_id=ca_MyClientId&stripe_user[product_description]=My Product description&stripe_user[url]=https://somesite.come">Connect to stripe</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same thing, until I encoded the the "stripe_user[product_description]" part.  In your case,

```
stripe_user[product_description]=My%20Product%20description
```

should be

```
stripe_user%5Bproduct_description%5D=My%20Product%20description
```